# Obtener porcentaje de uso de RAM y DISK en Linux

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos

Básicamente me gustaría saber el comando en linux para obtener "ÚNICAMENTE EL PORCENTAJE DE USO" de RAM y DISK. Recalco "SOLO EL PORCENTAJE" porque me gustaría guardar dicho valor en un String sin hacerle antes ningún tratamiento.

Apreciaría mucho su colaboración. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: `df` y `free` proporcionan esa información, que has intentado hasta ahora? como lo guardas? donde lo guardas?

Comment: Es que utilizo un método en java concretamente en la clase jsch para realizar conexión ssh y ejecutar comandos, y posteriormente guardar los valores que arroja el comando(%CPU,%RAM,%DISK) en una variable String. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Despues de tantos intentos y de leer tantos post logre decifrar como solo devolver el % de uso de CPU, RAM y DISK. y los comandos que me sirvieron fueron los siguientes:

CPU:

```
grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}'
```

MEMORIA:

```
free -m -h -t | grep T | awk '{usage=($3*100)/$2} END {print usage "%"}'
```

DISK:

```
df --total | awk '{usage=($4*100)/$2} END {print usage "%"}'
```

Muchas gracias a todos los que de una forma u otra me ayudaron. Saludos.